# loud noise in front end tires at 60 mph

Tags: tires, noise

I have a 2005 Toyota highlander and the tires are making a loud noise as I hit 60 mph but after a few minutes it goes away and doesn't come back until I hit the highway again and get up to 60 mph. Does anyone have any idea what this could be? I have brand new tires on it and alignment as well. I have no vibration in the car at all just loud noise for a few minutes then gone.

Comment: What brand and size are your tires? If they're an offroad pattern, quite often they can make a 'humming' noise at speed.

Answer (score 3):

Tires heat up quickly during the first bit of driving. The heating tends to soften the rubber which changes how it contacts the road surface. How the tread blocks contact the road changes the sounds produced.

Tires vary greatly in design and materials which both affect the noise produced. Name brand expensive tires are carefully engineered to make a "white noise" type sound. Low end inexpensive tires are rarely so carefully designed.

If the air pressure is correct; the alignment and suspension are all OK; the rotation is up to date then replacement could the only recourse available.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you check your brakes first. This is usually a main suspect in loud noises if all other aspects are fine. 
Then it would also benefit you get a suspension check done at a tire fitment centre. They would be able to tell you if it something more complex such as ball joints, CV's, steering rack bushes giving in or any other part behaving strangely. 
Most tire fitment centres wont charge you anything for this unless they find the flaw that is causing the noise